# ¿Cómo copiar un directorio desde un SFTP a mi local usando phpseclib?

Tags: php, php5, sftp, phpseclib3

He logrado conectarme al servidor SFTP,listar todos los elementos (directorios y ficheros), filtrarlos (eliminar los directorios "." y ".."), y descargar ficheros pero aún no logro descargar o copiarme las carpetas.

No encuentro nada en la documentación oficial que me permita indicar un directorio y que se me descargue completamente en local. Cuando digo "completamente", no únicamente me refiero a todos los ficheros que tenga en su interior, sino también a todas las subcarpetas (y subcarpetas de esta).

Uno de mis tantos intentos es el siguiente:

```
$this->sftp->exec('cp /carpeta_que_quiero_descargar/* /downloads/');
```

Comment: En el título de la pregunta dice fichero y en el contenido dice directorio. Podrías rectificar?

Comment: Lo había notado pero luego en el contenido de la pregunta menciono varias veces "directorio", por eso lo dejé tal cual, sin embargo, acabo de modificarlo como has sugerido.

Comment: creo q lo mejor seria, listas lo q necesitas descargar y con un bucle lo descargas archivo x archivo

Comment: @Carlos me queda claro que era un directorio. Sólo fue una observación en pos de mantener la consistencia del contenido

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu problema es el comando de linux que utilizas para la copia.

No se si ya lo has probado, pero como no indicas eso , lo voy a sugerir.

Si mal no recuerdo para copiar carpetas y subcarpetas tienes que agregar -r (indicando una copia recursiva)

Entonces tu comando debería ser:

```
       $this->sftp->exec('cp -r /carpeta_que_quiero_descargar/* /downloads/');
```

o

```
       $this->sftp->exec('cp -r /carpeta_que_quiero_descargar/ /downloads/');
```

te paso también un link para consultar.

https://ed.team/blog/mover-copiar-y-renombrar-directorios-en-linux

Saludos

Comment: ¿Hay forma de determinar cuándo se terminó la copia? ¿Hay otra forma de hacer esto con una función recursiva?